# App Crashes after building APK using Expo ESA

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, apk

quick update:
Finally, after a week found the problem.
I've added package-lock.json in .gitignore, after removing it from .gitignore it now works.

I'm working on a React Native app using Expo. When I run my app using the expo start command it works great, but after building the app using Expo ESA and installing on my mobile every time i try to open the app it crashes and this error is shown:

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes, stack:
anonymous@1:1143129
loadModuleImplementation@1:106186
guardedLoadModule@1:105735
metroRequire@1:105363
anonymous@1:1142534
loadModuleImplementation@1:106186
guardedLoadModule@1:105735
metroRequire@1:105363
anonymous@1:724292
loadModuleImplementation@1:106186
guardedLoadModule@1:105735
metroRequire@1:105363
anonymous@1:112516
loadModuleImplementation@1:106186
guardedLoadModule@1:105692
metroRequire@1:105363
global@1:104947
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:72)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
    at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

I've tried running expo doctor and updating dependencies but with no results. I've also tried to add Sentry but when it crashes nothing is logged to Sentry

Comment: it's very difficult to solve this issue from that error message alone, it could be anywhere in your code. my suggestion start from minimum working code, create apk build test on device, then try add 1 by 1 package or screen, until you found the causing issue. good luck

Comment: Finally, after a week found the problem.
I've added package-lock.json in .gitignore, after removing it from .gitignore it now works.

Comment: Because of package-lock.json on gitignore? I would never imagine gitignore causing the issue

Comment: never do I. but this is what happened with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing package-lock.json from .gitignore solved my problem.